# Python dateutil, check which value is given

Tags: python-dateutil

I am parsing an excel document and get date time values...

I am using dateutil to convert it to python datetime values...

For example if incoming value is '2012' i need a way to understand that only year is given

or if value is '13:05' only hour-minute is given.

```
from dateutil.parser import *            
def convertToDatetime(inValue):
    #if inValue is '2012' i need a way to understand only year is given. Can i do this while     parse method is used?
    rVal = parse( inValue )
    return rVal
```

How can i accomplish this?

----- EDIT ----

I can ask the question in this way too:

If only the year is given dateutil completes the day and month with today's values... But i need null values for month and day if only year is given...

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709652/python-regex-match-date

Comment: Ok. but dateutil parse function is already doing that kind of checks and returns correct datetime values. Why can't we use the checks inside dateutil?

Comment: No, rather determine what sort of value you have in advance, pass it in, then you can ignore the irrelevant components once converted. If you want to change the auto-completion behaviour then have you considered editing the dateutil module itself to change that behaviour?

Comment: editing the dateutil module ? I could not find a setting like that in the docs?

Comment: it's just more python code, there is no "option". You can do whatever you want with these modules. For example, open up the file "parser.py" and search for "default". You will then see the code that puts in the default values if none are provided. You can change that code to get your desired behaviour. It's all "just" more python.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is yet to be implemented in the [dateutil](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil) module. You can modify this [snippet](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/403#issuecomment-312321202) as per your requirement though.

```
from dateutil import parser
from datetime import datetime
import warnings

def double_parse(dt_str):
    dflt_1 = datetime(1, 1, 1)
    dflt_2 = datetime(2, 2, 2)

    dt1 = parser.parse(dt_str, default=dflt_1)
    dt2 = parser.parse(dt_str, default=dflt_2)

    if dt2.year != dt1.year:
        warnings.warn('Year is missing!', RuntimeWarning)
        return dt1.replace(year=datetime.now().year)

    return dt1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(double_parse('2017-04-05'))
    # 2017-04-05 00:00:00

    print(double_parse('03:45 EST'))
    # stderr: RuntimeWarning: Year is missing!
    # 2017-01-01 03:45:00-05:00
```