# Date Regular Expression Django

Tags: django

What is the regular expression for date "January 22, 1955, 1:20 am" in Django? What's good resource for commonly used regular expressions like dates and others?

Comment: You should post what you have tried yourself so people could help you more instead of asking people to do the work for you. You could try python regex on line test here: http://pythex.org/. For python regex doc: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: In Django you have a  urls.py, views.py, and a template index.html. So when in www.domain.com.index.html, index.html gets executed first, then checks urls.py for the the correct view to execute, then views.py executes that return a response to index.html.  Is that the correct execution flow in Django?

Comment: What does that comment have to do with your question about regexes for dates? Come to that, what does your question have to do with anything in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

To handle dates and string formats for dates, just use the regular Python datetime module.

Example: [Python regex match date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709652/python-regex-match-date)

Reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior