# If line contains date in MM/DD/YY print line

Tags: python, date

I want to identify if a string contains a date formatted as MM/DD/YY. It can be any date, as long as its in that format. Not sure how I would denote this.

```
for line in f:    
    if date in line:
        print(line)
```

Data:

```
>Unneeded text<

Account: 5

03/29/18      7,885,216.93-    208,557,351.68     200,672,134.75    2.18        12,151.81                                           
03/30/18      7,885,216.93-    208,557,351.68     200,672,134.75    2.18        12,151.81                                           
03/31/18      7,885,216.93-    208,557,351.68     200,672,134.75    2.18        12,151.81                                           
04/01/18      7,885,216.93-    208,557,351.68     200,672,134.75    2.18        12,151.81                                           
04/02/18     10,487,227.15     202,979,865.76     213,467,092.91    2.17        12,867.30                                           
04/03/18     26,149,970.46-    209,222,696.72     183,072,726.26    2.18        11,086.08                                           
04/04/18     13,606,232.52-    217,761,977.25     204,155,744.73    2.18        12,362.77                                           
04/05/18     29,929,731.83-    228,565,335.73     198,635,603.90    2.19        12,083.68                                           
04/06/18     32,832,695.61-    235,134,802.88     202,302,107.27    2.19        12,306.70                                           
04/07/18     32,832,695.61-    235,134,802.88     202,302,107.27    2.19        12,306.70                                           
04/08/18     32,832,695.61-    235,134,802.88     202,302,107.27    2.19        12,306.70                                           
04/09/18     31,908,656.83-    232,249,566.41     200,340,909.58    2.19        12,187.38                                           
04/10/18     20,367,782.42-    229,302,450.95     208,934,668.53    2.19        12,710.17                                           

>Unneeded text<

Account: 6

03/29/18      7,885,216.93-    208,557,351.68     200,672,134.75    2.18        12,151.81
```

This is one account's worth of data. There are approx 30 accounts I need to iterate through. The issue is that each section of data is separated by some text that is not necessary.

My current script grabs the account # along with yesterday's data:

```
for line in f:
        if "ACCOUNT: " + Account in line:  
            TAccount = Account     
                for line in f:
                    if rdate.strftime("%m/%d/%y") in line:
                        print(line)
```

I was hoping that there would be a way to just find any string that began with a date formatted as MM/DD/YY

Comment: have you considered regex?

Comment: I don't know what that is, what would I do with that?

Comment: [Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)

Comment: This seem to be a duplicate of [Check if string has date, any format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25341945/check-if-string-has-date-any-format?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python regex match date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709652/python-regex-match-date)

Answer (score 4):

You can use this regex to recognize this model MM/DD/YYYY :

`date_regex = '(0[1-9]|1[12])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])\/(\d{4})'`

[regexr example](https://regexr.com/3o5fs)

and you can use this for MM/DD/YY :

```
date_regex = '(0[1-9]|1[12])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])\/(\d{2})'
```

[regexr example](https://regexr.com/3o5fj)

Comment: I added the above to my script and implemented it as:

    for line in f:
        if date_regex in line
            print(line)

but nothing prints

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re` module to find data and you consider to validate the date if it is valid using `datetime` module

```
for line in f:
    match=re.search(r'(\d+/\d+/\d+)',line)
    _date = match.group(1)
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(_date,"%m/%d/%y")
        #To DO
    except:
        pass  #not valid date
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would extract the date elements from the string:

```
month=int(f[0:2])
day=int(f[3:5])
Year=int(f[6:8])
```

Checking if these give a valid date might be a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using **regex**

```
import re
s = "dssdfsdfsdfsdf 10/01/18 ssdfsfsf dsfsdfsdfsd"
print(re.findall("\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}", s))
```

**Output:**

```
['10/01/18']
```

In your case:

```
for line in f:
    date = re.search("\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}", line):
    if date:
        print(line, date.group())
```

Comment: Do you think  99/99/99 is an valid date? You match it.
Please check your answer before posting.

Comment: it is matching 10/01/1811  also

Comment: Good progress, however this only gives me the first date of each. My dates range from 3/29 to today and I only get 3/29.

Comment: @ChaseRaab. Can you post your data?