# Extract all dates with different format from a text using python

Tags: python, regex

How do I extract all the dates in different format from a text file using python ?
For information, the text is written in french.

**Ex:**

> [04/30/2009 blablo 06/20/98 something else 8/2/69 happen in this moment 1/25/2011 maybe this one 9/3/2002 other blablabla Janvier 2005 this year 1974]

PS : 
I am not able to know all the formats of dates because the function that I seek will have to apply on many texts

Comment: Try looking into regex

Comment: Getting the slash-separated dates is quite easy with regex: `(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)` but the _textual_ dates will need precise definitions in order to capture them.

Comment: What have to tried so far?  Please post your code.

Comment: If you are not able to know all formats the program won't be either, and also every person who is asked to help you. except perhaps you ask some AI / neural Network People.... but still: you should be able to define what you're searching for

Comment: Do you have a set of predefined date formats besides the ones you mentioned?

Comment: To get started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709652/python-regex-match-date

Comment: @trollster No, the main idea is to extract dates from contracts. So, the function has as an input the contract and must output the dates.

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a [python library](https://github.com/akoumjian/datefinder) for this, albeit in english.

#### Example (from the github):

```
string_with_dates = """
...
entries are due by January 4th, 2017 at 8:00pm
...
created 01/15/2005 by ACME Inc. and associates.
...
"""

import datefinder

matches = datefinder.find_dates(string_with_dates)

for match in matches:
    print match
```

#### Output:

```
2017-01-04 20:00:00
2005-01-15 00:00:00
```

To translate this to french, I'd suggest taking a look at [top of this file](https://github.com/akoumjian/datefinder/blob/master/datefinder.py), at the top of the file there is a big ol' pile of regex in English, this could be translated to French.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron, but this function extract also some prices. It is not able to make difference between date and other number.
ex : 8560$ --> 8560-05-17