# Finding multiple dates from a string in Python without using parsing packages

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to find dates in a string, but code doesnt work when I use "/" as a date separator. Also if i enter multiple dates. it returns only one.
I'd like to use all valid date separators viz "/" "-" "." and get all the dates in the string.
Also i'd like to use all the date formats like ddmmyy mmddyy yymmdd yyyymmdd ddmmyyyy mmddyyyy.

```
str = " here is some text in 31-01-2019 my string 01/02/2019 for fun 02.02.2019"
match = re.search('\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}', str)
date = dt.strptime(match.group(), '%d-%m-%Y').date()
print(date)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python regex match date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709652/python-regex-match-date)

Comment: that doesn't answer my question if i have multiple dates in a string

Answer (score 0):

```
re.findall(r'\b\d{2}[-\./]\d{2}[-\./]\d{2}\b|\b\d{4}[-\./]\d{2}[-\./]\d{2}\b|\b\d{2}[-\./]\d{2}[-\./]\d{4}\b',lsstr)
```

output : `['31-01-2019', '01/02/2019', '02.02.2019']`
Use this regexp to find all the dates present in the string.

Comment: this syntax is not working on the 3rd line in date var & still returns only one string

Comment: Don't copy and paste the code. There may be indentation issues. Type it manually and then see the results.

Comment: If you want to work for all formats, them let me know.. I'll modify the answer accordingly.

Comment: I've made the changes